# Can a ESP8266 and a HC-SR04 be friends?

Tags: sensors, arduino-ide, esp8266

I have some existing code that I've been using with an Uno and a HC-SR04. In order to make my project less expensive, I'm trying to port everything over to a ESP8266-01.

The last hang up I've been running into is that it appears that the ESP8266 doesn't support the pulseIn function.

```
duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
```

Any idea on how I can change the pulseIn function with interrupts or something else?

Lastly I've done a lot of searching for using a HC-SR04 with a ESP8266 and while there are a couple examples out there, I haven't seen anyone do it with Arduino code...

Comment: This may be helpful, I have come across a library - newping.h that doesn't use pulseIn (https://bitbucket.org/teckel12/arduino-new-ping/wiki/Home). The code fails to compile when I include that whole library. I just want to be able to use the part to bypasses pulseIn and haven't figured that out yet.

Comment: `Can a ESP8266 and a HC-SR04 be friends?` Have you tried food, wine, candles and romantic music?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pulseIn()` is actually a very simple function.  As long as there is a microseconds counter of some form available you can easily enough roll your own.

Also, I don't know which implementation of the ESP8266 plugin you are using, but [the one I use](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino) has [pulseIn available](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/esp8266/hardware/esp8266com/esp8266/cores/esp8266/core_esp8266_wiring_pulse.c).

Comment: I'm using the same version of ESP8266 plugin as you are, thanks for letting me know that pulseIn() is already supported! I didn't see any mention of it in the reference documentation - http://arduino.esp8266.com/versions/1.6.5-947-g39819f0/doc/reference.html. I was also told that my code will compile even if all the functions aren't supported.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with pulseIn() until the proper initializing code was put in setup(). 
As follows:

  pinMode(TRIGGER, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(TRIGGER, LOW);
  delay(2);
  pinMode(ECHO, INPUT);

TRIGGER and ECHO were initially defined at top of code with other variables as follows:
  #define TRIGGER 13 // Data pin D7
  #define ECHO    12 // Data pin D6

My HC-SR04 board was wired to D7 and D6, but D1 and D2 are often used.

Project was a 'Tide' reporting system. A work in progress.
Also found HC-SR04 board was  unstable if using 3.3vdc as VCC. Works better if the HC-SR04 board VCC is tide to Vin on the ESP8266 board.